# ReplicaSet doesn't delete Replication Controller pods?

Tags: kubernetes

When I created a replicaset and a replication controller the replicaset didn't delete the replication controller's pods and I'm trying to understand why.

Context: I gave the replicaset matchLabels section the same labels as in the replication controller's labels section.

From my understanding replicaset ensures there is only a set amount of pods with the specified labels in the matchlabel section. When I create a pod on its own with the same labels the replicaset gets rid of that pod but it doesn't seem to delete the replication controller's pods. So I guess my question is does the replication controller keep its pods running or does the replicaset not interfere with replication controller pods?

Answer (score 0):

A replica set is an updated version of a replication controller you can take it this way. one supports set-based selector.

You can consider both as different.

for list of replicas sets you can

```
kubectl get rs
```

for list of replication controller you can

```
kubectl get rc
```

Replication controller concept: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/

replica sets concepts : 
 https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/

Comment: That didn't really answer my question. I'm trying to figure out why replicaset doesn't delete the replication controllers pods

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to `metadata.ownerReferences`. As per [Replicaset documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/#how-a-replicaset-works):

> A ReplicaSet is linked to its Pods via the Pods’
>   metadata.ownerReferences field, which specifies what resource the
>   current object is owned by. All Pods acquired by a ReplicaSet have
>   their owning ReplicaSet’s identifying information within their
>   ownerReferences field. It’s through this link that the ReplicaSet
>   knows of the state of the Pods it is maintaining and plans
>   accordingly.
>
> A ReplicaSet identifies new Pods to acquire by using its selector. If
>   there is a Pod that has no OwnerReference or the OwnerReference is not
>   a Controller and it matches a ReplicaSet’s selector, it will be
>   immediately acquired by said ReplicaSet.

[Owners and dependents](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/#owners-and-dependents) page also supply you with an example of how to use and control `metadata.ownerReferences`

I played with nginx..

1) rs.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: nginx-set
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  # modify replicas according to your case
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

2) rc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      name: nginx
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

3) manually create pod: `kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --labels="app=nginx"`. In case of such start pod has NO ownerReferences at all

Both RS and RC delete nginx pod, if I start it manually. They both rely on `"app: nginx"` label.

However you can deploy simultaneously  both RS and RC - they will not touch each other pods.

The key difference is their OwnerReference.

RS:

```
ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: nginx-set
```

RC:

```
ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicationController
    name: nginx
```

So suppose this is thats why rc and rs live in peace and not touching each other ))